# Declare AppBar in another dart file and instantiate it with an different file

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

It's the 4th day of my Flutter. I used to use Unity.
Currently my project has 3 pages; **Home**, **Profile**, **Settings**

These pages are transitioned using `Navigator`.
The `AppBar` is declared in the `Scaffold` within each page, but the `AppBar` for all pages is the same.
So I have to write three of the same code. (always need to write and modify the same code as the number of pages increases in the future)

So I thought it looks good to declare AppBar as a variable and the page would just call it.
Like this:

```
//originappbar.dart
AppBar originAppBar(
    backgroundColor: .....
)

//home.dart
class ShowHome extends StatelessWidget {
  ShowHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String route = '/home';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: originAppBar(), ....

 //profile.dart
 //Same as home.dart
```

In the above example, I'm trying to assign the `originAppBar` created by `originappbar.dart` to `appbar:` in `home.dart` or `profile.dart`.

But I can't declare AppBar as a variable.
I'm confused because I thought I could make AppBar a variable.
What's wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PreferredSizeWidget originAppBar = new AppBar(
 backgroundColor: .....
)

//home.dart
class ShowHome extends StatelessWidget {
  ShowHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String route = '/home';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: originAppBar, ....
//profile.dart
//Same as home.dart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stateless widget like:

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget{
///Here goes your duplicated code
}
```

And just use that CustomAppBar everywhere.

Or create a widget `CustomScaffold` that is nothing more than the scaffold that you use in all your pages but with the CustomAppbar and any other hanges made.